# SpeechSynthesizer in C# creates wav that has 22kHz... needs to be 16kHz

Tags: c#, wav, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer, sample-rate

My C# application needs to covert text to wav file and inject it into a Skype call. The code that creates the wav file is below. The problem is that the file has 22kHz sample rate and Skype accepts only 16kHz.

Is there any way to adjust this setting?

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create("message.wav"))
{

System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer speechEngine = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

 speechEngine.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);
 speechEngine.Speak(number);
 stream.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SetOutputToWaveFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586885%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) has an overload that accepts a [`SpeechAudioFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.audioformat.speechaudioformatinfo_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) parameter, which can be used to set the sample rate.  <strike>Don't see one for `SetOutputToWaveStream()`, oddly, but</strike> since you're writing to a file anyway, that should work.

Edit:

As @Hans points out, the correct overload is [`SetOutputToAudioStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtoaudiostream%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to write to a stream.

Comment: SetOutputToAudioStream() is the alternative.

Comment: @Hans, Ahh, I see.  Odd that they weren't consistent in their naming... `SetOutputToAudioFile()` for non-wave format, or an overloaded `SetOutputToWaveStream()`.  Updated answer. :)

Comment: Perfect solution. I have my wav files in just the right format!